# "mono app.exe" gives error "File does not contain a valid CIL image."

Tags: mono, raspberry-pi3

I've made the following as a simple test.

```
using System;
namespace test
{
    class App
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Then compiled and moved the entire bin folder to my pi and tried to run it using "mono app.exe" but I get the error in the title. How do I run compiled .Net core executables using mono on raspberry pi?

Comment: Why there are so many raspberry pie questions and everyone goes to Mono? Good guides like https://taras.codes/blog/hosting-an-asp-net-core-application-on-raspberry-pi-3/ should be the primary source to clear all the doubts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realized that mono is .NET framework.
I installed .NET core runtime and it worked.
[I followed this guide](https://edi.wang/post/2019/9/29/setup-net-core-30-runtime-and-sdk-on-raspberry-pi-4)